# Migration error with devise

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, devise, migration

Hey I have a problem with my page here. I used a gem 'devise' to create a migration file for "users" I might have forgotten to `rake db:migrate` after that but I'm really not too sure what I did here to duplicate anything.

I ran the code `rails g devise user` I may have forgotten to `db:migrate` and then ran the code `rails g devise:views`

It's for a TeamTreeHouse project, and I'm sorry if I was too confusing with my question...anyway here is the error message.

```
==  AddDeviseToUsers: migrating ===============================================
```

-- change_table(:users, :email)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you already have an "users" table

Try to run: `rake db:reset` to run your migrations after drop and recreate your database.

**UPDATE**

This command will clear all data you have stored (unless is present in your seeds.rb), be careful to use this if you have important data in your database.

Comment: Isn't this dangerous? What if he has important data he does not want to lose?

Comment: You're right, I don't think can dangerous to a TreeHouse project, but my answer was Updated to set this warning.

Comment: Thanks guys! Yea its not dangerous at all...I'm just learning the basics here so it might be good to make some mistakes haha! I put your code in and it came out with another error saying sqlite already exists

Comment: rake db:reset
Couldn't drop db/development.sqlite3 : #<Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - C:/Users/RANDY/Projects/Taybook/db/development.sqlite3>
db/development.sqlite3 already exists

Comment: Is your rails server running? if yes, you should stop it.

Comment: Swell! Thanks guys! I do appreciate

Answer (score 0):

his command will clear all data you have stored (unless is present in your seeds.rb), be careful to use this if you have important data in your database.

Comment: how to neglect migration error in order to update my profile soon